# Pyinstaller opens Stockfish in console

Tags: pyinstaller, stockfish

I have made a GUI (using PySimpleGUI) where you can play against Stockfish (I used python-chess module). I make an .exe-file using Pyinstaller --noconsole, but when i run it, it opens Stockfish in a console. When I run it form source, in PyCharm, Stockfish runs silently in the background.

The relevant lines of code are (I guess):

`engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(engine_filename, shell = False)`

and, a bit later,

`best_move = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=20)).move`

Any advice on how I can make Stockfish run silently in the background also form the .exe-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your engine like below.

```
import subprocess

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(
            engine_filename,
            shell = False,
            creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

See [python subprocess ref.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)